# What type of bond would be formed if dyz orbitals overlap along the z axis?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I know that when two $\ce{p_z}$ orbitals overlap in a particular direction - along the z axis - they form a sigma bond. Now, if two $\ce{d_{yz}}$ orbitals overlap in same direction, which type of covalent bond would be formed?

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer the question, you should understand that - since everything is symmetric - the answer would be the same if we took two $\ce{d_{yz}}$ orbitals along the x-axis, two $\ce{d_{xy}}$ orbitals along the y-axis, etc.

Have a look at this snippet I picked from [Wikipedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Quintuple_bond_orbital_diagram2.png) (by Jeremy77, public domain):

[image: dxy orbitals overlapping laterally along y axis]

Here you can see the overlap of two $\ce{d_{xy}}$ orbitals along the y-axis constructively (in the same phase). There are four lobes overlapping, which would lead to a total of two nodal planes. Such a bond is a speciality of $\ce{d}$ orbitals and it is called the delta ($\delta$) bond.

Now, can you understand what the answer to your question would be?

---

See also: [Which d orbitals can form Sigma, Pi, Delta bonds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/66574/5026)

Comment: Just tell me in one word what is the answer of this question.

Comment: @RohanSachdeva I said in my answer it's the delta bond

Comment: Is delta bond resulting when $d_{x^2-y^2}$ and $p_y$ overlap along $y-axis$?